# Breadcrumb ordered wrongly

Tags: breadcrumb

```
/*Breadcrumb*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'seobreadcrumbs' ) ) : 
function seobreadcrumbs() {
$separator = '&rsaquo;';
$home = 'Home';
echo '<div xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" class="seobreadcrumbs">';
global $post;
echo '  <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
You are Here :- <a rel="v:url" property="v:title" href="http://www.how2blog.in">Home</a>
</span> ';
$category = get_the_category();
if ($category) {
foreach($category as $category) {
echo $separator . "<span typeof=\"v:Breadcrumb\">
<a rel=\"v:url\" property=\"v:title\" href=\"".get_category_link($category->term_id)."\" >$category->name</a>
</span>";
}}
echo '</div>';}
endif;

function show_crumbs() {
if(is_single() || is_tag() || is_search() || is_404() || is_page() || is_category()) { ?>
<?php seobreadcrumbs(); ?>
<?php }}

add_action('thesis_hook_before_content','show_crumbs');
/* End*/
```

I use these codes to show breadcrumb trail. The problem I’m having with it is, some times its getting messed up let me clarify suppose I’ve category named

Social Media parent category is Facebook

When I publish a post under facebook It should show like

```
# Social Media >> Facebook
```

But some times facebook is coming 1st then Social Media 2nd like this:

```
# Facebook >> Social Media
```

And Google also displaying this way.

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Comment: Does it *sometimes* show up with the child category before the parent category, or does it *always* show up that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thought is that the issue is here:

```
$category = get_the_category();
```

If `get_the_category()` is returning categories in reverse-hierarchical order, then you can do this to put them back in order:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$category = array_reverse( $category );
```

However, I'm confused by this:

> But some times facebook is coming 1st then Social Media 2nd...

If it is only happening *sometimes*, and not *always*, then I suspect that there is an issue somewhere else.

Comment: Oh my gosh it works :) I've no words left to tnx you... just want to say my hat goes off to you mate... God bless you...